# How to get the timestamp for the system lock/unlock of ubuntu 22.04 with the user's inactivity time? (Not login/logout.)

Tags: script, bash-scripting, monitoring, lock, ubuntu-22.04

I want to get the user's lock & unlock timestamp in a single script or command, as in "last" command I can see the user's name with system's login & logout timestamp. How can I get the user's lock/unlock timestamp & after logged in how much time the activity has been done, that time too, in ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: [Detect workstation/System Screen Lock using Python(ubuntu) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395579/detect-workstation-system-screen-lock-using-pythonubuntu) may be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

From
[How can I know when my screen was locked last time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435069/how-can-i-know-when-my-screen-was-locked-last-time)
I quote the answer by Jeroen van Ingen:

> FWIW: what works for me on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with Unity, is
> monitoring DBUS with the following command:
>
> ```
> dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.canonical.Unity.Session'" ...and then
> ```
>
> monitoring for "Locked" and "Unlocked" events. Example output:
>
> > signal time=1525269138.855107 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86735 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session;
> > interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=LockRequested
> >
> > signal time=1525269139.409261 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86892 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session;
> > interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=Locked
> >
> > signal time=1525269151.238899 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86937 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session;
> > interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=UnlockRequested
> >
> > signal time=1525269151.791874 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86938 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session;
> > interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=Unlocked

Comment: the solution you've given won't worked. As I'm not getting proper output with the above command usage, also I've tried with the script.